# PHP. Как добиться записи кириллицы в файл .docx при использовании библиотеки PHPWord?

Tags: php, xml, объекты, ms-word, phpword

Всем привет!

1. Есть объект SimpleXMLObject: $al->{'response'}->results->grouping->group[0]->doc->title->hlword[0];
2. В нем лежит слово "Почему" на русском. Хочу записать это слово в файл .docx, генерируемый библиотекой PHPWORD. Пишу в коде: $section->addText($al->{'response'}->results->grouping->group[0]->doc->title->hlword[0]);
3. В получившемся файле появляются кракозябры, как при ошибке кодировки.

**Мои действия:**

4. Вывел в тот же файл, той же библиотекой другой элемент массива объектов:

   `$section->addText($al->{'response'}->results->grouping->group[0]->doc->url);`

Там лежат латиноязычные ссылки - файл Word корректно отобразил англоязычные ссылки.

5. Вывел в браузер русскоязычный элемент с функцией определения кодировки:

`var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($al->{'response'}->results->grouping->group[0]->doc->title->hlword[0]))`

Он ее определил как UTF-8.

6. Написал с помощью функции addText() из арсенала библиотеки русскоязычное слово напрямую:

   `$section->addText("Привет!");`

Слово корректно записалось и читается в Word.

7. Подумал, что PHPWord "не знает" русский язык, но коды, предложенные в документации не срабатывают: https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html
8. Выполнил в консоли команду:

   echo (string)$al->{'response'}->results->grouping->group[0]->doc->title->hlword[0];

Вышло вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В узле hlword[0] действительно лежали слова "Почему" и "Существует" - существует достается на следующей итерации.

Comment: Попробуйте вывести значение на экран консоли `echo (string)$al->{'response'}->...->hlword[0];` - верно выводится?

Comment: @Jigius Здравствуйте, попробовал. Скриншот результата приложил к тексту вопроса, в самый низ..

Comment: @Jigius да, выводится как нужно..